# Software to do formal expansion of $(1+x)^{8/3}$ or an any fraction

Tags: calculus, math-software

I am looking for something light ( suggestions for install are ok)
Typically I need to have enough terms for $a^4\left(1+a^{-1}\right)^{\left(8/3\right)}$
None of symbolab / geogebra / quickmath seem to give the result.
I did it by hand , yet my need is to check and do many other formula.

Comment: You can use what you know from theory to help assist your calculator in producing more terms.  Specifically, use the (*generalized*) binomial theorem to know that $(1+x)^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n}{k}x^k$ and know that $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n\frac{k}{~}}{k!} = \frac{\prod\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}(n-i)}{k!}$.  You can plug in those expressions even if the calculator you attempted to use wasn't initially going to expand the expression in the first place.

Comment: Alternatively, use [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=expand+%281%2Bx%29%5E%288%2F3%29&key=t4xhu) and be sure to include words like "expand" or "series expansion" and the like

Comment: @JMoravitz . Thank you very much for the wolfram alpha suggestion it works. Subquestion : how to get a list of binomial values like $\binom{8/3}{k}$  ?

Comment: @JérômeJEAN-CHARLES: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=table%20of%20binom%20(8%2F3%2Ck)%20for%20k%3D0..10&dataset=

Comment: @joriki Thank you. How did you find the command ?

Comment: @JérômeJEAN-CHARLES: I don't remember; it's a very long time ago.